# Protecting a public XenServer host

Tags: xenserver

I have experience in Amazon AWS deploying EC2 instances and VPN access, configuring a VPC, etc. Now, I'm deploying a private cloud using a small XenServer host. It's working on my private network, and is doing really good.

Well, I need to put the server on the public network, but I'm on a budget, and can't invest on a firewall or other external security device to protect it. So, right now, things are like this:

```
Internet <---> Router <---> XenServer host
```

I will appreciate some direction about what I should research to reach these goals:

- Protect the XenServer host (for example, is it possible to enable `ufw` or something like that? Where?)
- Give it VPN access to the VM guests (I think it will be similar to AWS -- configure a gateway to Internet, configure a VM with a VPN server, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

XenServer is based on CentOS so it doesn't have UFW. Out of the box it is quite secure but you can review and amend the firewall configuration by looking at the /etc/sysconfig/iptables files. I like to (for exampele) disable external access to port 443 which means that I have to log in and add a rule to allow my IP address access if I wan to use XenCenter.